# PDF showing only 1 page while generating from XML layout

Tags: java, android, xml, pdf

I am generating a `PDF` file from my `XML` file in which i've created a `RecyclerView` and have shown some more data. The problem is when the data is less, it is showing fine on 1 page but when the data exceeds 1 page then it is not displaying it on the 2nd page. Have applied many methods but are not working.

This is my code to create `Bitmap` Image of that `XML` file

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }
```

And here i am converting it to `PDF` format

```
private void createPdf() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
        String targetPdf = "/sdcard/test.pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            btn_generate.setText("Check PDF");
            boolean_save = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // close the document
        document.close();
    }
```